# ghci: module ‘main:Main’ is defined in multiple files - in new small stack init build ghci package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I try to setup a `stack` based Haskell IDE with vscode and start with a small project created with `stack init` and then added a second module in `src` and added some dependencies in `package.yaml`. It builds ok but when I start `stack ghci` I have warnings:

```
Warning: Multiple files use the same module name:
         * Paths_primo found at the following paths
           * /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0/build/autogen/Paths_primo.hs (primo:lib)
           * /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0/build/primo-exe/autogen/Paths_primo.hs (primo:exe:primo-exe)
* * * * * * * *

GHCi, version 8.10.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 3] Compiling Lib              ( /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/src/Lib.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 3] Compiling YamlRead         ( /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/src/YamlRead.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/app/Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, three modules loaded.
```

There seems to be a confusion with `autogen` and with `Paths_primo` (`primo` is the name of the package). What am I doing wrong?

General question: what is the correct way to clean a stack project to "start over" after some experimentation? Is is correct to delete the `cabal` file and the `stack-work` directory. Waht is with `stack.yaml` and 'stack.yaml.lock`?

Comment: You have done nothing wrong. It seems you have ran into [Stack issue #5439](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5439). The GitHub issue links to an explanation and offers a workaround.

Comment: thank you for the information! I will not use the workaround as the warning has no ill effects.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a harmless warning reported at [Stack issue #5439](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5439), whose underlying cause is [hpack issue #303](https://github.com/sol/hpack/issues/303). A workaround to get rid of the warning is disabling the generation of the `Paths_` module for your `primo-exe` executable, by adding the following to its section in `package.yaml`:

```
when:
- condition: false
  other-modules: Paths_primo
```