# exclude temporarily a file from a `stack build` when using hpack (package.yaml)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hpack

One may work on a haskell file in the `source-dirs` directory and decide for now not to include this file in a `stack build`. Is there a simple way to exclude temporarily the file form the build?

The obvious work-around is to move the file to another directory, but I hope this can be achieved inside hpack in a simple way which I did not find in the hpack docs.

Comment: I haven't tried it (I don't usually use hpack), but it looks like adding the module to an `other-modules` field under an always false conditional (as in the workaround from [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66600663/2751851)) would do the trick. (I'm basing this on [the description of how hpack autofills the module fields](https://github.com/sol/hpack#library-fields).)

Comment: Thank you for the hint (I had see but not carefully read the document you reference). The trick seem to work, but is far from elegant; I guess there is a need for excluded list of modules! I will suggest it.

Comment: You're welcome. Given that it works, I have promoted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the module under an always false conditional will make hpack's auto-discovery skip it:

```
when:
- condition: false
  other-modules: Excluded.Module
```