# stack ghci with error module ‘main:Main’ is defined in multiple files:

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a small haskell program which builds and executes with stack ok. When I start it with `stack ghci` I have an error message which I do not understand and cannot proceed.

```
GHCi, version 8.10.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 3] Compiling Lib              ( /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/src/Lib.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 3] Compiling YamlRead         ( /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/src/YamlRead.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/app/Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, three modules loaded.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/.ghci

<no location info>: error:
    module ‘main:Main’ is defined in multiple files: /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/app/Main.hs
                                                     /home/frank/Workspace11/primo/app/Main.hs
```

I do not see why the same `Main` is listed twice in the exact same file.

I had a somewhat similar warning message about `Paths_primo` which is a known bug ( Stack issue #5439 ) and I fixed following the advice [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579458/ghci-module-mainmain-is-defined-in-multiple-files-in-new-small-stack-init/66600663#66600663).

What is the cure against this error? I have not used `stack` much - am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a sign that `Main.hs` or `Main` is inadvertently listed multiple times in your Stack `package.yaml`, in such a way that `ghc` is invoked with multiple occurrences of it.

This error is possible to reproduce easily with GHC alone, for example:

```
> echo 'main = putStrLn "hello"' > Hello.hs

> ghc Hello Hello.hs
<no location info>: error:
    module ‘main:Main’ is defined in multiple files: Hello.hs Hello.hs
```

I would run Stack with `--verbose` and see how GHCi is being invoked, and double-check the `package.yaml` and generated Cabal file. (If you edit your question to include that, we may be able to offer more specific help with it.)

I can think of several possible reasons for this, such as literally listing `Main` or `Main.hs` multiple times (e.g. in `exposed-modules`, `other-modules`, `main-is`); or an interaction like a missing option value in the `ghc-options` field causing subsequent flags to be misinterpreted.

Comment: Thank you for the hint to use --verbose. The result is a bit hard to digest... The problem eventually was in the `.ghci` file, where I inlcuded `:load Main` which I had copied from a file I used a year ago. Fixed, but still not clear why. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: "I would run Stack with --verbose and see how GHCi is being invoked, and double-check the package.yaml and generated Cabal file. (If you edit your question to include that, we may be able to offer more specific help with it.)" What do these two sentences mean?

Answer (score 0):

`Main.hs` can be listed multiple times in GHCi invocation when it is present in multiple components. Typical way when this happens is:

1. You create a project with `stack new` which contains single `src/Main.hs` file, so `package.yaml` has an executable entry and no library entry.
2. Then you add a library and use `source-dir: src`. Now `Main.hs` is listed in two components: `myapp-lib` and `myapp-lib-exe`. Assuming you package name is `myapp`.

To solve the problem you should move Main.hs to app dir and update `executables:source-dirs` to `app` in `package.yaml`.

So the problem may happen when `Main.hs` is listed in multiple components in `package.yaml`, for example in `executables` and `library`.

Comment: I have found the cause of the error several days ago - you seem not to have read that commentary. your analysis of the cause does not apply.